# Is using registerTempTable with Spark SQL API lazy?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

In order to compose Spark SQL, SQL API queries together I need to call the `Dataframe.registerTempTable` function to create an in memory table to store my intermediate result.  Then I can perform other SQL API queries over it.

If I'm just using the Dataframe API I could compose a new dataframe using the DSL and then perform multiple operations on that intermediate result without explicitly creating a temp table.

Is it possible to have the same performance in both situations?  In other words, is the creation of the temp table lazy?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`registerTempTable` is lazy and doesn't cache or materialize the data at all. It simply puts the name with corresponding logical plan in the session catalog.

So ignoring SQL parsing overhead and hash-map lookups there should be no performance difference whatsoever.